# Rewriting the Return Address with a Format String Vulnerability

Tags: c, security, format-string

I have a C program which looks somewhat like this:

```
void doSomething() {
    ... <does something> ...
}
void vuln(char[] buf) {
{
    ...
    printf(buf);
    ...
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ... <get buf from user> ...
    vuln(buf);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is create a format string that will cause `doSomething()` to be executed. ASLR is off, so I know the exact addresses of the `doSomething()` function.

Through some trial and error, I found that the return address can be printed out by passing `"%15$x"` as a format string. In my case, this return address is `0x8048ab8`. I want to rewrite it to `0x804866b` (the address of `doSomething()`). How do I do this? I couldn't find a good explanation of this online.

In general, if how do we write to an address that can be accessed using `"%A$x"` where `A` is some number?

Comment: since `doSomething` isn't in the call chain, it's not on the stack, I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: What you are trying to do is undefined behaviour. It may work on certain platforms with certain compilers and certain compiler flags. You also need to understand the assembly language of your platform and have a look on ther generated assembvly code and/or debug at the assembly level

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  theoretically is should be possible if ASLR is off. You "just" need to replace the return address on the stack with the address of `doSomething`. The difficulty is to obtain the address of `doSomething`.

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: This usually can't be done with `printf` alone, since it will not write to local buffers. If the function used e.g. `sprintf` or `gets` or similar function prone to buffer overflows then it would be possible.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `printf` will write to a user-supplied pointer when the `%n` format code is used. This is not always easy to exploit, but it is possible. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have the address of the `doSomething` function, so obtaining it isn't an issue